# How to calculate time difference between 2 objects in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator

i'm sorry if the title doesn't coincide with the request but thats the best i could come up with at the time.

So i have an ArrayList that takes an object as parameter.

```
private List<Movement> walked = new ArrayList<>();
```

Note: Movement is the name of the class
I have a method that calculates the time difference between two time strings and it works wonderfully.

My dilemma is that when i click a button, an object is added to the ArrayList. i want to know the time duration between this new click, and the next click as the time of both actions in being recorded.

i'm doing stuff like this in my onClickListener

```
Movement move = new move();
move.setTime("current time");
walked.add(move);
```

So based on the number of clicks, i want to be able to get the objects in the list, get their respective time and calculate the time difference for each and output it as i click on.

My function for doing the time calculations works i'm just unable to iterate properly. This is what ive tried;

```
for(Movement x:walked){
  Toast(TimeCal.getDuration(x.getTime(),  "i'm to put the previous object time here") + " min(s)");
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `for(int i = 1;  i < walked.size(); i++){
   Movement current = walked.get(i);
   Movement prev = walked.get(i-1);
Toast(TimeCal.getDuration(current.getTime(),  prev.getTime()) + " min(s)")
}`

Comment: What you want to do is click a button and every time you click you want to display how much time has passed since you clicked it last time? And if this is the case, do you need the history or clicks for statistics or something like that, or can you just use the last click and then discard it?

Comment: Exactly @palako, i don't really need the click stats. The time difference is what's most important. Thanks

Comment: @Shark, i get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: @shark got it working using your code. Thanks, can you post it as an answer so i give you proper credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compare the current click to previous click in one loop, you shouldn't use a `foreach` but rather a `for` loop. Something along these lines:

```
if(walked.size() > 0)
for(int i = 1; i < walked.size(); i++) { 
    Movement current = walked.get(i); 
    Movement prev = walked.get(i-1);
    Toast(TimeCal.getDuration(current.getTime(), prev.getTime()) + " min(s)") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to my comment in your question, forget the ArrayList, all you need is a reference to the latest click.

You are creating a Movement move in your onClickListener. Save that as an object  attribute instead of a local variable, and when you get the next click, on the onClickListener add a bit of code to check if that variable is set. If it is, just do the time difference between the Movement you have stored in the object attribute and the one you just got.

Comment: oh snap, sorry @palako, i forgot to mention that i'll have to save all the clicks (time) later that's why i'm using the arraylist

Comment: save them as well to use them later, or just do the same thing I told you but keeping the array global and access the last element for comparison.